# Area configuration aggregation error after install Porto theme

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.3.1, custom-theme, porto-theme

i try install Porto theme to Magento 2.3.1, but i get some problem. I try

```
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile 
sudo rm -rf pub/static/*/*; sudo rm -rf var/*/*; 
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

this commands for magento and

```
sudo addgroup webmasters
sudo adduser $USER webmasters
sudo chown -R root:webmasters /var/www
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
sudo chown -R www-data:webmasters application/cache/ [etc...]
```

more for set up permissions. I attach some pictures about problems. What is solution? 
Thank you in advance for your help
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sequence of command instead:

```
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade 
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not working. I run second command and get latest error (in terminal). And I get permission error and I fix fix chmod -R 777 /var[image]